# Deeper understanding of Document Object Model

Tags: dom

I recently encountered this on one of my project and I don't think I have the full understanding of this thing at all. The only thing I know are the following: 
 

-That DOM prevents scripts that are loaded on blocking the rest of the page. 
 
-Html files and other page source codes are parsed and turned into DOM, with which, when you inspect it or go to view page source, the DOM format of the code is what it will throw you. 
-I was also able to implement DOM on our project through the help of a tutorial. 

Now, my questions are: 

-Is the code in the devtools the DOM? 
-Does DOM adds security features on a system? 
-Since DOM was widely implemented in the layout engines of the web browser, is there any other advantages of using DOM aside from it prevents possible blocking of the rest of the codes of the page? 

Thanks guys.

Comment: who voted this down? I don't mind as long as you can justify why or I'll flag it.

Comment: I did not down-vote you, but this question has been asked and answered many times on this site. Search 'DOM' and 'Document Object Model'.

Comment: I only have three questions here. Actually, I partially understand DOM. I just want few clarifications here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM (Document Object Model) is all about the code/object hierarchy within a given system/node. It is symbolic of the branches of an upside-down tree. It forces the different layers of code to always have a parent-child-sibling relationship.
Any code inside another block of code is a child of the larger block. For html, the html tag is the parent of all other tags, followed by the head, then body tag.
 Most all displayed content is in the body section, with one division creating the main page you see. After the division tag you have the ul / li / p / a tags. Sometime the span tag is used as a wrapper for the 'a' or 'p' tags.
 The 'ul' tag is a child of the div tag it is in, and the 'li' and/or 'p' tag is a child of the 'ul' tag.
 Only the span tag varies in location when used, depending on its need to keep objects and/or text inline.
 The lowest possible child (or leaf in a node tree) is either a 'p' tag or an 'a' tag.
 No other tag can be used inside the 'a' tag.
 A sibling is referred as a tag or node of the same level in the tree, but in an adjacent div or ul or li tag. Their relationship is not defined normally, unless there is a need to do so.
 *In summary, the DOM is used to insure order and readability in html / XML /SQL and other software systems*. It does NOT guarantee good working code by itself, but it sure helps create efficient working code early in the design stage.
Also, new coding functions are being employed that can bypass or modify the way the DOM behaves. Angularjs and MEAN, which includes a micro-server and node.js, are trying to turn a clients web page into a de-facto desktop application, such that the request to the server become as minimal as possible.
 These new functions do not contradict the DOM model, but act as a wrapper so action/editing/motion on a webpage appears instantly without having to contact the main server.
 During periods of no user action an update is sent to the main server, so the website and the PC stay in sync in terms of changes that are at least semi-permanent.
Please read as much as you can about these topics, because every year something new is added.

Comment: Check out: http://www.quirksmode.org/ for info on how different browsers implement the DOM in slightly different ways.

Comment: did you down vote my post? I just hunger for knowledge. Oh well, base on what you have said, DOM does not add security features, and the only reason that DOM is implemented is for readability? I think I am missing something here. I'm a little confuse. Base on your answer it appears that DOM is able to avoid blocking of other codes of the page as stated here <http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write> through forcing "Parent-Child" relationship of nodes? by the way, why am I not allowed to directly call the script if readability is what DOM ensures?

Comment: @ArchieAzares. The DOM is about organizing structures or code by hierarchy, nothing more than that. It gives Javascript / SQL a path to all objects on a html page or SQL table.

Comment: then how is it able to prevent scripts that are loaded on blocking the rest of the page which was stated on the tutorial?

Comment: The DOM does not take action on its own. The code used for a given theme follows DOM hierarchy procedures. That is why web pages and server tables MUST follow the DOM hierarchy so that function calls and table searches work properly. It would take 1,000 pages to explain the finer details, such as different DOM types, so please read all that you can. If something is blocked or accepted, it is code following DOM rules that makes that happen.